# How to parse color (saved data) from one controller class to another controller class?

Tags: ios, background, uiimageview, uicolor

I'm practically new in IOS dev.

I would like to ask, let's say if i have a controllerA.m and I have a

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIColor *savedColor;
```

How can I parse the savedColor from `controllerA.m` to `controllerB.m` whereby i wish to set the background color of an `UIImageView *mainImage` same as the savedColor?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `backgroundColor` property of the image view using the controller's color property like this:

```
mainImage.backgroundColor = controllerA.savedColor;
```

or if `mainImage` is a property of the view controller, then use:

```
self.mainImage.backgroundColor = self.savedColor;
```

---

*note: if a parse is actually involved, you should provide a longer description of the origin of this color -- what you are asking is not very clear (at least, to me)*